# Help with drawing a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am attempting to draw a simple figure with tikz:

[image]

Thanks for your help

This is what I have so far:

```
%\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[very thick,->] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\draw[blue!80,fill=blue!50] (2,0) circle (.2cm);
\draw[blue!80,fill=blue!50] (4,0) circle (.2cm);
\draw[blue!80,fill=blue!50] (6,0) circle (.2cm);
\draw[blue!80,fill=blue!50] (8,0) circle (.2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you draw the circles as circular nodes, then you can use the `label` syntax to place the labels above and below them.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
```

Let's load some fancier arrow tips to improve on the current arrow.

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

If we are going to draw the circles as nodes, it makes sense to define a standard style with the required settings to avoid having to repeat the same settings and to make it easier to modify them, if required.

```
  [
    my blue/.style={blue!80,  fill=blue!50, minimum width=4mm, circle, inner sep=0pt},
```

This should draw circular nodes which look pretty much like the `circle`s defined in the original code.

We want sans text so let's set that for the picture.

```
    font=\sffamily
  ]
```

We start as before, but we substitute one of those fancier arrow tips for the plain one, using `-{Stealth[]}`.

```
  \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[]}] (0,0) -- (10,0)
```

We could place each node separately using

```
\node [my blue, label={[text=blue!80]above:<label>}, label={[text=blue!80]below:<label>}] at <location> {};
```

but that's a lot of typing, so let's use a loop to draw the 4 circles we want and place the labels. The lower labels we can derive by adding a `0` to the number of the step: `10`, `20`, `30` and so on. So we want a variable for the upper labels - `\i` say - and another one to keep count - `\n` say. Then our loop will look like this:

```
    foreach \i [count=\n] in {AA,BB,CC,DD}
    {
      node [pos=\n/5, my blue, label={[text=blue!80]above:\i}, label=below:\n 0] {}
    }
```

The position for each node is also calculated, as shown here, from `\n`. So this is a pretty efficient way to draw the circles and label them.

While we are here, we might as well add a coordinate where we want the 'f1` marker to go, in the middle of the line, but it will be easier to add this marking as an additional step.

```
      coordinate [midway] (f1)
```

Finally, we add a node to the right of the very end of the line for the 'temp' label.

```
      node [right] {temp};
```

Now we just need to add the vertical marking and the label 'f1' where we placed the coordinate `(f1)` above. We can do this using relative coordinates using the `+` syntax. If we draw downwards, then the label node can simply be added `below`.

```
  \draw [very thick] (f1) ++(0,2mm) -- (f1) -- ++(0,-2mm) node [below] {f\textsubscript{1}};
```

We use a `\textsubscript` rather than `$f_1$` because, this way, we keep to sans serif as desired.

```
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And we are done!

[image: temp arrow]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    my blue/.style={blue!80,  fill=blue!50, minimum width=4mm, circle, inner sep=0pt},
    font=\sffamily
  ]
  \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[]}] (0,0) -- (10,0)
    foreach \i [count=\n] in {AA,BB,CC,DD}
    {
      node [pos=\n/5, my blue, label={[text=blue!80]above:\i}, label=below:\n 0] {}
    } coordinate [midway] (f1) node [right] {temp};
  \draw [very thick] (f1) ++(0,2mm) -- (f1) -- ++(0,-2mm) node [below] {f\textsubscript{1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

I thought I would add the following method to produce the diagram with a single line of TikZ. This uses the `decorations.markings` library in place of relying on a second line of TikZ code. Although I thought of doing this originally, I'm not convinced it is worth the trouble for a single line. Nonetheless, following an offer of code to implement basically the same idea, I thought it might be useful to show how to do it with the existing library.

As well as deleting the second `\draw` command, we can eliminate the coordinate specification for `(f1)` as we don't need it. Instead, we add the node and the vertical line as a `decoration`, which we apply to the first `\draw` as a `postaction`. This means that the decoration is drawn *as well as* the original line, as we want, and not *instead of it*, as it would be if we simply said `decorate`.

The additional options needed for the `\draw` are

```
postaction=decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{|}\node [below, yshift=-1mm, anchor=north] {f\textsubscript{1}}; } }
```

The contents of `decoration` specifies the type of decoration, `markings`, and the settings for that decoration. `mark=at position .5` puts it at the midway point and `with {<stuff>}` specifies what to use as the marking. The `\arrow{<arrow tip>}` is specifically provided by the `decorations.markings` library for the easy use of arrow tips as markings. We then add the node below it, shifted down a little, as before.

The result:

[image: marked temp line in one step]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    my blue/.style={blue!80,  fill=blue!50, minimum width=4mm, circle, inner sep=0pt},
    font=\sffamily
  ]
  \draw[very thick, -{Stealth[]}, postaction=decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{|}\node [below, yshift=-1mm, anchor=north] {f\textsubscript{1}}; } }] (0,0) -- (10,0)
    foreach \i [count=\n] in {AA,BB,CC,DD}
    {
      node [pos=\n/5, my blue, label={[text=blue!80]above:\i}, label=below:\n 0] {}
    } node [right] {temp};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can decorate a path with the syntax `node [`*location*`] {`*contents*`}`. For example, *location* can be `above` or `right=10pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% to reduce typing
\newcommand{\decor}[2]{node [above=10pt] {#1} node [below=10pt]
  {\textcolor{black}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick, ->] (0,0) -- (10,0) node [right] {temp};
\draw[blue!80,fill=blue!50] (2,0) circle (.2cm) \decor{AA}{10};
\draw[blue!80,fill=blue!50] (4,0) circle (.2cm) \decor{BB}{20};
\draw[blue!80,fill=blue!50] (6,0) circle (.2cm) \decor{CC}{30};
\draw[blue!80,fill=blue!50] (8,0) circle (.2cm) \decor{DD}{40};
\draw[very thick] (5,0.5) -- (5,-0.5) node [below] {\(f_1\)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can add `text=black` in the second node of `\decor`

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with a loop. Here is some commented version

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick,-latex] (0,0) -- (8,0);% That arrow head is called 'latex'

\foreach \x % do things multiple times with index \x
  [count=\xi] % when going through the list also count the index with \xi
  in {A,...,D}{ % tikz understands alphabetical sequences
    \node[fill=blue!10,circle,% give the node options
          label={[text=blue!10]90:\x\x},% put the letters
          label={[text=blue!10]270:\xi0},
          inner sep=2mm%increase the size a bit
          ]
          (n-\xi) % give a name
          at (2*\xi-1,0) % place them at odd numbered x's
          {}; % Nothing is written inside the disks
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```